# detect chains interface to each others

Tags: python

My data in a text file PDBs.txt looks like this:

> 150L_A
>
> 150L_B
>
> 150L_C
>
> 150L_D
>
> 16GS_A
>
> 16GS_B
>
> 17GS_A
>
> 17GS_B
>
> ...etc

The end result needed is:

> "Does First chain of 150L A interfaced with second chain B"
>
> "Does First chain of 150L A interfaced with third chain C"
>
> "Does First chain of 150L A interfaced with forth chain D"
>
> "Does second chain of 150L B interfaced with third chain C"
>
> "Does second chain of 150L B interfaced with forth chain D"
>
> "Does third chain of 150L C interfaced with forth chain D"
>
> "Does First chain of 16GS A interfaced with second chain B"
>
> "Does First chain of 17GS A interfaced with second chain B"
>
> etc...

in chains.txt output file.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This question looks very similar to your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099441/how-to-print-different-character-of-repeated-words-in-python . Can you maybe adapt the accepted solution to this new problem of yours?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, yes , I know it might have the same outline, but the output needed will be a total difference, I will highly appreciate your help and inspiration, thank you

Comment: Please: Update the formatting of this question so it matches your older one.

Comment: Please specify how, I am new member, thank you

Comment: Gladly. The important points are written down here for you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask